# Motivation behind studying the asymptotic structures

Tags: general-relativity, asymptotics

I am trying to explain to myself the motivation behind studying the asymptotic structures at null, time-like and space-like infinities (For the purposes of this post, I will stick to four dimensional Minkowski spacetime). I think I have the motivation behind the first two of them down, but not the third.

1. Null Infinity is interesting since radiation and fluxes of massless particles can reach it. One must understand these in order to answer questions such as energy loss due to gravitational radiation, or charge fluxes. Further, information can travel from the bulk to null infinity only, and is therefore an important thing to study in that context as well. Geroch's paper notes that

> At null infinity, one's description involves "what the system is doing through time", i.e. the dynamics of the system.

I agree with this.

1. Time-like infinity corresponds to the starting and ending points of massive particles travelling along geodesics. I would presume that these would be of importance when describing "In" and "Out" states of a quantum theory.
2. Space-like infinity is a little harder for me to motivate. In Geroch's paper, he notes

> At spatial infinity, "what the system does" is never even recorded. Rather, one sees only the state of the system", once and for all.

Here are my questions:

> 1. Are the motivations I provided above for null and timelike infinity correct? Is there anything more to add?
> 2. What does Geroch's comment mean? Surely, in general, a system will evolve in time. What then describes the "state of a system"?? Is it the initial conditions? What, precisely is the information about the system that is stored at space-like infinity?

I have often seen null and spacelike infinities being discussed thoroughly without much literature on time-like infinity. While the extensive study of null infinities does not surprise me, the study of spacelike infinity does. I therefore feel like I am missing something quite important here.

EDIT: I just had a thought. It seems to me that both null and spatial infinity can be reached in a finite value of coordinate time (appropriately defined). On the other hand, time-like infinity can only be reached asymptotically. This implies that study of time-like infinity requires taking two limits $r \to \infty$ and $t \to \pm \infty$, whereas, study of null and spacelike infinity involve single limits like $r \to \infty,~v$ fixed and $r \to \infty,~t$ fixed respectively. Maybe this has something to do with my answer, but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: In the [Penrose diagram of Minkowski space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Penrose.PNG), only "information" coming from the past time-like infinity may reach the space-like infinity, so we could say that only the "initial state" is seen at spatial infinity.

Comment: Probably we need put boundary conditions when solving Einstein's equations. To this end, we need a precise description of the boundary which contains null infinity and spatial infinity. We are also interested in the isolated systems. To properly define them, we also need to know what are null and spatial infinities.